# Gregorian calender: Confusion with calling the method on the object

Tags: java

The program below is part of a tutorial.I have some confusion here
with the below lines:

```
     GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                gCal.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 1);
                this.expiryDate = gCal.getTime();
```

shouldn't the above code be something like this:

```
GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
SomeDatatype variable = gCal.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 1);
      this.expiryDate = variable.getTime();
```

Following is the part of the original program:

```
package models;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import utilities.GenderType;


public class Customer {

    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String email;
    private int customerNumber;
    private GenderType gender;
    private boolean isvalid;
    private Date expiryDate;

    public Customer(String title, String firstName, String surname, String address,
            String phoneNumber, String email, int customerNumber, GenderType gender) {

        setName(title, firstName, surname);
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.isvalid = true;
        GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
        gCal.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 1);
        this.expiryDate = gCal.getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: add method returns void, which means you cannot assign it to any data type.

add method modifies the gCal object and adds year to it, so when gCal.getTime() is called it has updated date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `GregorianCalendar` class, `add()` method returns void.

The reason for this is that it performs an action on the internal data of the `GregorianCalendar`. It adds the defined portion of time to it.

You don't need to get something returned from `add()` method. The same object is already updated after calling it, so, you only have to get the new time value it contains.

See [GregorianCalendar add() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) reference.

Comment: here we add a year to the whatever date gCal.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 1);                                                    but how does following line of code still hold that extra year? because we are not calling that add method, we are only calling the get time method
                this.expiryDate = gCal.getTime();

Comment: @DePaul That's right. The new value is already included in the `gCal` object. You don't need another object.

Answer (score 0):

GregorianCalendar's add method dont have any return type.
as per the java doc it have below signature.

> public void add(int field,
>          int amount)

Its return type is void means its not returning any value thats why you can't do like as below.

```
SomeDatatype variable =gCal.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 1);
```